# What is the order in which physical volumes are used in a volume group?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, ssd, lvm

I have a volume group which contains 2 physical volumes

1. 400g on a 7200rpm hdd
2. 250g on an ssd.
   Can I ensure that the ssd is used first/ the hdd is only used when the ssd is full? Note I will have var an temp on the hdd only and boot(and efi) on the ssd. To accomplish this I will have a total of four logical volumes: /, /boot, efi, /temp and var

Thanks for your help. I am installing arch linux and using lvm 2

Comment: With a typical span, this is usually the case, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make both the SSD and the HDD (or partitions on them) LVM physical volumes, you put them in the same volume group, and you start creating logical volumes, then LVM will fill one of the physical volumes first, then it will start on the other one. I don't know which physical volume it starts filling first — but it actually doesn't matter.

If you want to put specific physical volumes on the SSD, just put the SSD and the HDD in different volume groups, and put the logical volumes on the volume group you want.

But I suspect this isn't what you want. If you want **files** to go to the SSD first, and the HDD to be used only once the SSD is full, LVM can't help you. LVM doesn't know anything about the filesystem. It doesn't know what part of the volume is used to store files (file content or metadata) and what part doesn't currently contain useful information.

The filesystem knows what parts of the storage contains useful data. But most filesystems treat the underlying volume as a single, uniform thing. They don't know that one part of the storage is faster than another, and even if they knew they wouldn't support moving blocks around to favor the fastest part.

[Btrfs](https://en.wikipedai.org/wiki/Btrfs) is more sophisticated than most filesystems, and it includes [support for multiple devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices). But I think even Btrfs doesn't have a mode that corresponds to what you want.

A common configuration is to set up the SSD as a cache for the HDD. In this configuration, the volume is as large as the HDD, and the SSD contains data that is also present on the HDD or at least has reserved space on the HDD. In Linux, this works through [bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/), and as with many things [the Arch wiki has good explanations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache). With bcache, you'd make put the root filesystem on the HDD, and make the SDD a cache for that partition.

Some notes regarding your partition scheme:

- Separating `/var` from `/` doesn't make much sense.
- `/boot` and `/efi` don't need to be fast so they can be tucked away on the HDD. You don't need a separate `/boot` with UEFI.
- `/tmp` is normally a tmpfs, living in RAM/swap, rather than an on-disk filesystem.
- You forgot swap. Swap should be on the SSD alone, since it needs to be fast.

Comment: I have 32gb of ram, so I don't think I'll be using swap. Ill look into bcache. It sounds promising. While I've heard of a ramdisk, I never thought of putting tmp on it. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: After looking at bcache I think I'll pass for now. Support seems a little flaky.I bee wanting to give back to the community. Maybe I can get the ball rolling  on my feature for lvm