# Encrypting multiple new system partitions at once, when they're spread across two physical disks

Tags: debian, lvm, btrfs, luks, debian-installer

I am installing Debian. I have two physical disks, and I would like to spread my system partitions across both for better performance. I also want to luks-encrypt my system, and preferably encrypt all of my partitions at once. I heard it's better that way, because then I won't have to decrypt them individually on each boot. And it seems to me that I don't want full disk encryption, since I only want to use a fraction of each disk for my system, and use the rest for other things.

I tried configuring LVM for this purpose, because I thought it may let me encrypt all of my partitions at once. But:

- If I add all of my partitions (premade `/`, `/home`, `/boot`) to a single volume group, they get blended together. When I then create logical volumes inside this VG, the installer does not let me chose which partition should host this LV. According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245572/478273), it is not possible to have control over which disk gets used, if they're part of one VG.
- If I add each partition to a separate VG, as [the above mentioned answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245572/478273) suggests, then they appear as different devices to encrypt, and thus would be encrypted separately. This would defeat the point of why I wanted to use LVM in the first place.

Am I missing something, or am I screwed? Should I use something other than LVM? Or am I screwed, and do I have to pick one of the two?

1. Encrypting all 3 partitions at once, with one key
2. Having control of which partition goes to which disk

And if so, which one is more significant?

- Being able to r/w from `/` and `/home` simultaneously doesn't sound all that beneficial, or is it? Perhaps it might speed up post-login system startup?
- If I encrypt disks individually, will I then need to enter multiple passwords on each system boot?